# 'az automation runbook start' command doesn't wait for compellation

Tags: azure, azure-cli, azure-automation, azure-runbook

I'm trying to create an Azure DevOps pipeline to run a few Runbooks by a specific order.
My pipeline currently looks like the following:

```
trigger: none

pool: <mypool>

jobs:
    - job: AzureCLI 
      steps:
      - task: AzureCLI@2
        inputs:
          azureSubscription: '<mysubscription'
          scriptType: 'bash'
          scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
          inlineScript: |          
            az config set extension.use_dynamic_install=yes_without_prompt
            az automation runbook start --automation-account-name "myaccount" --resource-group "myrg" --name "runbook-1"
            az automation runbook start --automation-account-name "myaccount" --resource-group "myrg" --name "runbook-2"
```

Thing is, when I run it like that what it does is triggering both runbooks in parallel. It triggers runbook-1 and then triggers runbook-2 without waiting for runbook-1 to finish.

In the [Az CLI Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/automation/runbook?view=azure-cli-latest#az-automation-runbook-start) there is no parameter like --wait-for-compellation or something like that.
There is a different command: 'az automation runbook wait' which I thought might wait after triggering the runbook with 'az automation runbook start' but it doesn't, it just exits immediately.
Anyone knows a different way to make the command hang until compellation?

Comment: instead of start we can use below command "az automation runbook wait --automation-account-name "myaccount" --resource-group "myrg" --name "runbook-1" --created".  Wait is the command keeps CLI in a waiting state until the condition is met on that runbook-1, which was already created earlier.

Comment: But I don't want to test if the runbook has been created or not, I want to test if a job I trigger using 'az automation runbook start' has been completed or not and the command you recommended would check if the runbook has been created or not.

Comment: we have several Optional Parameters
 
--created : Wait until created with 'provisioningState' at 'Succeeded'.
--custom : Wait until the condition satisfies 
--updated : Wait until updated with provisioningState at 'Succeeded'.
our requirement we can use either custom / updated at the end

Comment: Try with this command "az automation runbook start --automation-account-name "myaccount" --resource-group "myrg" --name "runbook-1" -MaxWaitSeconds 1000 -Wait"

MaxWaitSeconds  : Specifies the number of seconds this cmdlet waits for a job to finish before it abandons the job. The default value is 10800, or three hours.

Comment: Answer to your first comment:
That command checks the runbook's provisioning state and not the job that was created from it and once a runbook is triggered its' provisioning state doesn't change.

Answer to your second comment:
The "az automation runbook start" command doesn't have the flags you specified:
unrecognized arguments: -MaxWaitSeconds 1000 -Wait
Also in the docs there's no reference to them.

Comment: Thanks for the patience. The only solution I have found here is via the DevOps pipeline is to integrate PowerShell scripts.
1. Integrate PowerShell task in pipeline 
2. We need to start runbook via PowerShell
 Start-AzAutomationRunbook -AutomationAccountName "myaccount" -Name "runbook-1" -ResourceGroupName "myrg"
it will start a runbook called runbook-1 and waits until it has completed, and then displays its output.
refer: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/start-runbooks
repeat the steps 2 again for another runbook-2.  Hope it will work.